# print not working in Swift 3 extensions

Tags: swift, parse-platform

I'm new at Swift 3 and I try to make a `print("Test")` in a Widget extension.

I tried the same code in **ViewController.swift** and It works ok. I don't know why it works there but it doesn't on **TodayViewController.swift**. I can't access to `objects` too.

```
func loadData() {
    let query = PFQuery(className: "Noticias")
    query.whereKey("titulo", equalTo:"Es Navidad")
    query.findObjectsInBackground(block: { (objects : [PFObject]?, error: Error?) -> Void in
        if error == nil {
            // The find succeeded.
            print("Successfully retrieved \(objects!.count) scores.")

            // Do something with the found objects
            if let objects = objects {
                for object in objects {
                    print(object.objectId!)
                }
            }
        } else {
            // Log details of the failure
            print("bad day homie")
            print(error!)
        }
    })
}
```

I attach I picture to see it clearly. If I try to print on the file marked as Work, it works. But if I try it on the file marked ad NO, it doesn't.[image]

Comment: And the error message is?

Comment: I'm not getting an error. It's just not printing the line "Successfully retrieved..."

Comment: Why don't you put some print message before the query, just to be sure it works fine?

Comment: I did it but not working. I added prints in the whole file and nothing printed on console.

Comment: So you put print on viewDidLoad and it doesn't work? If this is true, are you sure your VC is properly connected, and the segue is working fine?

Comment: Yes, it doesn't work on viewDidLoad. I edited the question with more info.

Comment: I don't see the edit.

Comment: You have it now. @i6x86

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/134431/discussion-between-dani-polo-and-i6x86).

Comment: To be honest I'm on the phone using the app and I don't remember my password so I can't join the chat.

Comment: @i6x86 thanks man, I'm going crazy with this. If you have any idea, is really appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is extremely difficult to retrieve print messages from an extension. The problem is that it's an extension! It isn't running in your app, so it doesn't arrive at your console. *Sometimes* I find you can solve this problem by switching the debugged process in the Debug Bar at the top of the debug area (at the bottom of the screen, not shown in your screen shot), but at other times this doesn't work.

I'll illustrate a possible technique that seems to be pretty reliable. Look at this screen shot:

[image]

"Expand" is an action extension. But my containing app is called "bk2ch13...". So how will I ever manage to pause at the breakpoint shown at the right, which is in the action extension? This is what I do.

1. First, with the screen as shown above, I build and run my containing app.
2. Then, I switch the target to the action extension:

[image]

3. Now I build and run *again*. But now I am trying to run an action extension, which you can't do, so Xcode asks me what app to run:

[image]

So I choose "bk2ch13...". So now we are running my host app again, *but we are debugging the extension*. So I use my host app to exercise the extension, and sure enough, *we pause at the breakpoints and `print` statements arrive into the console*.

[image]

Note, in that screen shot, how the debug bar clearly shows that we are talking to the extension, not the host app.